# Как пользователь сам смог восстановить удаленный ответ?

Tags: дефект

В вопрос: [Как интегрировать 1С с интернет-магазином?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/122096/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-1%D0%A1-%D1%81-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC) ответ одного из участников был помечен как низкого качества и, впоследствии, удален:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом в [списке ревизий ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/603472/revisions) можно найти следующее

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А также в [timeline](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/603472/timeline)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как возможно одним голосом восстановить свой ответ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Он был удалён из очереди проверки без голосов на *удаление*

#### (*рекомендации* были, *голосов* не было, это привилегия 20к+)

- Если удалил ответ **автор**, автор **может** его восстановить.
- Если удалили ответ из *проверок*, голосами за "рекомендовать удаление" (для чего 20к не требуется), автор **может** его восстановить. **[Произошло именно это.]**
- Если удалили ответ голосами за **удаление** (доступным только от 20к) (возможно, из проверок), то автор **не может** его восстановить сам, потребуются голоса от пользователей с правом голоса за восстановление (20к+). "Подать апелляцию" можно здесь, на Мете.
- Если удалил сообщение модератор, автор **не может** его восстановить. И даже 20к+-овые участники. Только модератор. Чтобы инициировать процесс, нужно тревогнуть ответ.

— [Источник](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/318749)

Comment: тогда к какому пункту отнести самый первый скрин? Либо это недоработка переводчиков?

Comment: @Grundy обновил ответ.

Comment: Не вижу ответа на вопрос про картинку с _**удалено** после проверки_

Comment: @Grundy а что вы ожидаете там увидеть? Пришло 5 рекомендаций, поэтому ответ и был удалён. Предполагаю, что удаление голосами приводит просто к "удалён {{кем}}", но это стоит проверить.

Comment: Я к тому, что написано именно _удалено_ а не _удалено из списка проверки_ например. И отображался он как удаленный. Какое-то непонятное поведение на мой взгляд :)

Comment: @Grundy на скриншоте написано "удалено после проверки".

Comment: Вроде бы такой же текст и при простом удалении, но не уверен.

Comment: @Grundy я тоже. Стоит пошариться на этот счёт.

Comment: А вот два голоса на удаление http://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/128729

Comment: @NickVolynkin, а для удаления вроде три надо

Comment: @Grundy точно, значит пользователь сам успел удалить и восстановить, что сбросило отданные голоса и вытащило вопрос из очереди проверок. Кстати, это эксплоит. )

Comment: @NickVolynkin, не, мне кажется он не сам удалял, а удалилось именно по результатам проверки